# PHP - Cannot redirect new visitor

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to make my index page redirect to a landing page if the visitor is not logged in.

(INDEX.PHP)

```
<?php

$newURL = "http://website.com/landing.php";

if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
    session_set_cookie_params(86400);
    session_start();
}
else
{
header('Location: '.$newURL);
die();
}
```

....................(rest of index.php)

When the visitor is not logged in, nothing happens and they just keep sitting on index.php
Is there an obvious reason why this doesn't work?

Comment: Your approach is off for several reasons. Start a session for everybody and then when someone is authenticated set a special session variable that says so. Check for that.

Comment: Can you use an example?

Comment: I have answered the question with an example

Answer (score 1):

you're starting the session after checking the $_SESSION variable. You should call session_start() at the top of the page.

Answer (score 0):

You're not telling this to do anything if they are not logged in. Just session_start(). You can add a header location to that first part of the condition.

```
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
    session_set_cookie_params(86400);
    session_start();

    // do something here, like redirect...
    header('Location: '.$newURL);
    die();
}
else
{
    header('Location: '.$newURL);
    die();
}
```

but this doesn't make a great deal of sense like this. I have to assume you're doing more in these conditions than just redirecting or setting a session. See John Conde's comment

Maybe you meant something more like this?

```
session_start();
if (empty($_SESSION)) {
    session_set_cookie_params(86400);
    header('Location: '.$newURL);
    die();
}
```

Comment: I only want them to be redirected to $newURL if they are not logged in.  This looks like it will always execute the re-direct

Comment: updated. this will only redirect if $_SESSION is empty.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
session_start();
session_set_cookie_params(86400);
if (!isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) {
    header('Location: '.$newURL);
    die();
}
```

**Notes**:

1. `session_start()` is called at the *top of file* and *before* attempting to use any session functionality.
2. I don't check to see if the session is set because it is automatically set when I call `session_start()`
3. I check for a specific variable I called `$_SESSION['logged_in']` which is set after a user successfully logs in. If soeone is not logged in, this variable will not be set so they will automatically fail this check and be redirected. Make sure when someone logs out that you `unset()` this variable or else they will still be logged in.